# consume from. vb net a webservice created in php nusoap

Tags: php, vb.net, web-services, nusoap

I created a web service nusoap my web service has complex types in the definition of the wsdl has a data type called "Persona", I've been consumed from php, but not as serious consume from. net vb,I added the reference in vs2008, but not like I have to send the parameters of type person (idpersona, nombre, apellido) I hope you can help me thanks.

### consume from php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(1);
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
$client = new nusoap_client("http://localhost/nusoap/server3.php?wsdl",'wsdl');
$id="78";
$nombre="donald";
$apellido="trump";
$params =array(
       'idpersona'=>$id,
       'nombrepersona'=>$nombre,
       'apellidopersona'=>$apellido);
$result = $client->call('insertar',array($params));

?>
```

### definition

```
<?php
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'Persona',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'idpersona' => array('name' => 'idpersona', 'type' => 'xsd:int'),
        'nombrepersona' => array('name' => 'nombrepersona', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'apellidopersona' => array('name' => 'apellidopersona', 'type' => 'xsd:string')         
    )
);

    $server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'ArrayOfPersona',
    'complexType',
    'array',
    '',
    'SOAP-ENC:Array',
    array(),
    array(
        array('ref' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType', 'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:Persona[]')               
    ),
    'tns:Persona'
);

$server->register(
    'insertar',                       // Nombre del método
    array('datos' =>'tns:Persona'),      // Parámetros de entrada
    array('return' => 'xsd:string'),      // Parámetros de salida
    SOAP_SERVER_NAMESPACE,                // Nombre del workspace
    SOAP_SERVER_NAMESPACE.'#insertar',        // Acción soap
    'rpc',                                // Estilo
    'encoded',                            // Uso
    'Insertar datos de la persona'            // Documentación
);
```

?>

an image [here](http://sia1.subirimagenes.net/img/2014/02/13/140213080917718332.jpg)

Comment: What is the error that you see?

Comment: I'm c# coder, but Dim algo as new localhost.Persona ?

Comment: consumption that I have is with a php array, but not how to implement consumer with vb, am I supposed to use the complex type(called Persona) declared in the wsdl... if I declare an array and pass it to the method (insertar)shows "value of type '1-dimensional array of string' cannot be converted to localhost.Persona"                        Dim referencia As New localhost.ServiceTest
        Dim algo() As String = {"98", "jhon", "deere"}
        referencia.insertar(algo)

Comment: You can not use an array, you may use the Persona class. Can you tell me the error that you see if go with the mouse over error in you visual studio? Or the error that you see if you try to build the project?

Comment: hello, and achieve consume the service from vb.net with this code thanks                                                           Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim referencia As New localhost.ServiceTest
        Dim algo As New localhost.Persona
        algo.idpersona = "10"
        algo.nombrepersona = "bill"
        algo.apellidopersona = "gates"
        referencia.insertar(algo)
    End Sub